# Unexpected value 'AngularFireAuth' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation while deleted an unused page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

Everything was perfect. I just deleted the unused page from the project but then an error pop out. Have no ideas where to locate it. this is just random error, I got.

I have imported AngularFireAuthNodule but still gives same error.

App.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire'; //To initialize firebaseconfig
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCk6-Ni2B15MgeYQI-N4AUBU4SNosL16Xc",
  authDomain: "msuapp-a559c.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://msuapp-a559c.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "msuapp-a559c",
  storageBucket: "msuapp-a559c.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "754024625194",
  appId: "1:754024625194:web:1a67567f9aebee4f3fbf53",
  measurementId: "G-GCBL53SM94"
};
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireAuth,
    AngularFirestore
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public appPages = [
    {
      title: 'Home',
      url: '/home',
      icon: 'home'
    },
    {
      title: 'List',
      url: '/list',
      icon: 'list'
    }
  ];

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

what could be the reason? EVen I had back up it in github, when cloned its gives me same error.

Comment: I think you need to import  AngularFireAuthModule an AngularFireStoreModule. You are importing the services i think but i can be wrong, dont have code here to test it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you imported the wrong Modules in your module.

According to the Docs: 
https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md

You need to import the

```
AngularFireAuthModule,
AngularFirestoreModule
```

insted of the

```
// The services you inject into your constructor
AngularFireAuth,
AngularFirestore
```